# Storyboards not Indexing ViewControllers in SVN

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, iboutlet

I'm having an issue with my storyboards failing to index ViewControllers while in SVN. I can manually set the custom class in the identity inspector and the code will compile, however, autocomplete isn't working as I type the custom class and all IBOutlets throw warnings that the class "does not have an outlet named..."

[image: Broken Outlets]

I can copy and paste the project outside of my SVN directory and the storyboard works correctly.

[image]

Any ideas what the problem could possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the issue was, but it seems to have been related to my SVN instance. A fresh checkout resolved the problem.